# Can I use HQL with JPA's @Query annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have two identical queries. One is being run by `entityManager.createQuery()` and the other as a `@Query` annotation in a `PagingAndSortingRepository`. The entityManager query runs fine, but the identical query in the @Query annotation returns an error.

Could it perhaps be because the `@Query` annotation is executing the query as JPQL and the `entityManager.createQuery()` executing the query as HQL?

Here are the two examples:

**@Query (does not work)**

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, UUID> {
    @Query("select p.user from Perspective p where p.organisation.id = 'c25c86a0-0d8e-4beb-9ba7-e38d932b8410'")
    List<User> findUsers();
}
```

```
could not resolve property: lastname of: org.jembi.appstore.service.entities.Perspective
// note: lastname is a property of user, not perspective.
```

**entityManager.createQuery (does work)**

```java
    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @RequestMapping("/query")
    @ResponseBody
    public void testQuery() {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select p.user from Perspective p where p.organisation.id = 'c25c86a0-0d8e-4beb-9ba7-e38d932b8410'");
        List<User> users = query.getResultList();
        users.forEach(u -> System.out.println(u.getFirstname()));
    }
```

Comment: I deleted and recreated the database and it started working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes here:

1. You're defining `@Param("organisationId")`, but not using it anywhere.
2. You're joining user: `join User u`, but never use it: neither is any relation to `Perspective` defined nor is it used in `where` clause.

Try this query:

```
@Query("select p.user from Perspective p where p.organisation.id = :organisationId")
List<User> findUsers(@Param("organisationId") UUID organisationId, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: I temporarily hardcoded the UUID for simplicity. I'm actually trying to get a User out, hence asking for p.user, but the query seems to be returning a "perspective" object.

Comment: @Spider no, it's returning `p.user`. Did my advices work?

Comment: This is the closest answer. Seemed I didn't need the join. I deleted and recreated the database and it started working automatically so I don't have an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

```java
@Query("select p.user from Perspective p join User u where p.organisation.id = 'c25c86a0-0d8e-4beb-9ba7-e38d932b8410'")
    List<User> findUsers(@Param("organisationId") UUID organisationId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I would advise you to rewrite it as:

```java
@Query("select p.user from Perspective p join User u where p.organisation.id = ?1")
    List<User> findUsers(String organisationId);
}
```

Why `String` and not `UUID`? I bet that HQL doesn't work with UUID. + UUID can be put in String.
Why have I deleted Pageable? I can't find in your query where you are using second parameter [Pageable].

Comment: The issue is not the finding of the record. I just temporarily hardcoded the UUID. The issue is that I'm getting back a perspective object instead of a User.

Comment: + Could you add here Entities that u mentioned in your queries?

Comment: I deleted and recreated the database and it started working automatically so I don't have an actual answer.

Comment: @Spider sometimes you should do it while u developing program)